# Wordpress posts in menu and custom classes

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

I'm new to WordPress and I'm trying to convert a pure HTML Theme to a WordPress theme. But I have a problem that I can't find a solution for. In the nav menu, I can't find a way to selectively add classes to the `ul` and `li` elements that WordPress generates as a menu.

Basically, I need to set different classes for 1 depth element, for two depth element, and for 3 depth element, and also check if the item has children and then also set a different class.

Then I have to put onclick script inside `li` element (i know these are buttons, but I think it should work with generated `li` items as well

```
<div class="tab">
    <button class="tablinks active" onclick="openCategory(event, 'cat01')">Science</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCategory(event, 'cat02')">Technology</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCategory(event, 'cat03')">Social Media</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCategory(event, 'cat04')">Car News</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCategory(event, 'cat05')">Worldwide</button>
</div>
```

I know this is quite much to ask for, but I'd be thankful for the help of any kind...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of this has to be / can be done in the `functions.php` file of your theme, see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/ , where you can define a container, its class, id etc.

The styles for the different menu levels can be achieved using according CSS selectors which contain combinations of direct child selectors, like `nav.your_class > ul > li > ul > li > ul { ... }`  and similar

Comment: Is there any way to do it without changing css? The css is quitebig and javascript works with classes too.

Comment: Another possibiilty is that you can assign *any* class to any individual menu item which you create on the WP menu page.

Comment: "Without CSS" - what do you mean? You asked about adding classes to the menu. What should these classes do if you don't have any relating CSS for them?

Comment: I do have css relating to them, i just want change basic classes of menu elements to clases i have. Because changing css files whould be real pain.

Comment: Well, then you can assign a class for the container in functions.php and use javascript selectors relating to that class to insert/assign all other classes you need. Or, as I wrote above, by assinging the classes to the menu items directly in the WP menu edit page (which only works for the `li` elements, however, not for the `ul` submenu containers).